# Endliche Anzahl

Tags: mathematics

In a vaguely mathematical context, could the 'endlich' in 'endliche Anzahl' ever not mean finite but only something like 'limited', so as to maybe include some transfinite cardinalities?

Comment: Generally, words can mean anything in a mathematical context if they are properly defined.

Comment: No, while “Anzahl” can possibly be understood to include infinite cardinalities (not a good idea), “finite” explicitly means “finite”. (It can also mean “finally”, but I do not see how that could apply here.) I do not think that this is a good question for this site, though, and I think that it's lacking context.

Comment: @chirlu: Prinzipiell hast du natürlich recht. Man kann im Ramen einer mathematischen Arbeit durchaus definieren, dass »endlich« z.B. der Name einer bestimmten Zahl sein soll (eine, zwei, endlich, vier, fünf, ...), oder dass »endlich« dasselbe wie »kongruent« oder meinetwegen »hermitesch« bedeutet. Aber das schafft nur Verwirrung und ist äußerst selten von Vorteil. Denn es gibt einige Standard-Begriffe, wie z.B. »Zahl«, »addieren«, »drei« oder eben auch »endlich«, die eine allgemein gültige Definition haben.

Comment: @chirlu: (Forts.) Die Definitionen dieser Standard-Begriffe lernt man in der Schule, und sie haben den Status von Default-Bedeutungen. Das heißt: Wenn (innerhalb eines Schriftstücks) nicht ausdrücklich etwas anderes definiert wird, gilt die Standard-Definition aus den Schulbüchern. Insofern ist immer eindeutig festgelegt, was mit »endlich« gemeint ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

The term »endlich« is well defined in mathematics. It is not so well defined in other topics, and can have different meanings outside of mathematics, but inside mathematics it is very clear, that »endlich« (»finite«) means »nicht unendlich« (»not infinite«).

But even outside mathematics »endlich« never means »limited«.

Outside mathematics »endlich« can mean:

- having an end
- at last, finally

The mathematical word for »limited« is »beschränkt«. This term is also well defined in mathematics, and also has different meanings outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

The term *endlich* is applied in mathematics to a set which can be put into one-to-one correspondence with the set {1, ..., n}, where n is a fixed positive integer. Or, in more mathematical jargon, there exists a bijective map from the set to {1, ..., n}. I e the answer to the question is "no".